# Achieving full justification in HTML and CSS: works in limited-quirks mode but no-quirks mode messes up the height

Tags: html, css, dtd, quirks-mode

I am trying to achieve *full justification* (as distinct from *left justification*, where the final line is left-aligned rather than justified) in HTML and CSS.

I have this document, plus a doctype definition:

```
<style>
    p {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    p::after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Justification</title>
<p>Foo bar</p>
<p>Foo bar</p>
<p>Foo bar</p>
```

With the HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`), the document is rendered in limited-quirks mode and each paragraph is fully justified as desired, with no extra space being taken.

With the HTML 5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) or with the HTML 4.01 (Strict) doctype (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
), the document is rendered in no-quirks mode and each paragraph is fully justified, *but takes an extra line of space*. Adding `height: 0` to the `::after` does nothing (it already has no height as the likes of `background: red` will demonstrate).

Live demonstrations: [HTML 4.01 Transitional](http://chrismorgan.info/temp/just4.html) and [HTML 5](http://chrismorgan.info/temp/just5.html) editions.

How can I get the HTML 4.01 Transitional rendering in the document with the Strict or HTML 5 doctype?

(Incidentally, I am aware of the workaround, given known contents, of assigning a value for `height` to the `p` element and depending on the default overflow behaviour to achieve effectively the right result. I will not accept that as an answer—I am seeking a *genuine* solution that can be done without hidden knowledge or JavaScript interception of resizing—assume the paragraph to be an arbitrary number of lines.)

Comment: Be careful not to call the HTML 4 transitional doctype "the HTML 4 doctype". The *strict* HTML 4 doctype will produce the same result as the HTML5 doctype does. So this is not a difference between HTML 4 and HTML5, but the difference between strict and almost-strict mode.

Comment: @BoltClock It’s so long since I’ve written HTML4 that I had forgotten about the strict doctype for some reason, even though I still recalled the XHTML strict/transitional divide!

Comment: @BoltClock: thanks for the hint there; you’re absolutely right, and that may help me in tracking it down. Hopefully it’s possible! I’ve updated the question to clarify these things.

Comment: The difference between left justification and full justification isn't just the last line, it's that in left justification the right side of the text can be ragged.

Comment: @JasonS: left alignment allows ragged right; left *justified* alignment (“left justification”) means that all lines are justified except the last, which is left-aligned. Right justified text is perfectly reasonable, for example, meaning that the last line is right-aligned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of the `:after` trick that tries to control the justification of the last line, use the [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) property, which is now rather well supported if you additionally use a `-moz-` prefixed version:

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}
```

Comment: Great! Didn’t know about that one, and it does exactly what I wanted. ☺ Not sure if Opera and Safari support it at present; the MDN article suggests they don’t, but it’s probably out of date, especially with regards to the Blink‐based Opera; for what I’m doing at present that’s an acceptable trade‐off anyway.

Comment: still no safari, iOS, opera as of Dec 2016. bummer.